# Is there a way to use PouchDB Inspector to inspect a remote device?

Tags: ionic-framework, pouchdb

I am using PouchDB with an Ionic APP, I debug it using Chrome and looking into the console. I would like to inspect the device pouchDB database like I do in chrome with the localhost version with [PouchDB Inspector](https://pouchdb.com/guides/databases.html#debugging)

Is there a way to do this? I do not see anything when I enter the PouchDB Inspector while in Chrome -> Inspect Remote Devices

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Sadly no. I exposed the object and used a lot of `console.dir`, `debugger`